# Java JTable keybindings working differently for tab and enter keys

Tags: swing, jtable, key-bindings

I have the following requirement:
1. When tab/enter key is pressed in JTable, read the value in selected cell and go to the next cell
2. This should happen whether the cell is in select mode or edit mode

The program written is not working when a cell with existing value is edited by pressing F2 key and enter key is pressed. For all other scenarios it is working fine.

**Update:** To recreate the issue, please follow the below steps:

Enter a in cell(0,0) --> press enter key --> use left arrow to go to cell(0,0) --> press F2 key --> Enter b in cell(0,0) --> Press enter key --> Here action performed is not called.

Please review the below program and let me know what changes to be done to meet the requirement.

TableTest.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TableTest extends JFrame
{
  private JTable table;
  private JScrollPane scrollPane;
  public TableTest()
  {
    setSize( 400, 400 );
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    table = new JTable( 10, 4 );
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed( false );
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed( false );
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled( false );
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );

    String solve = "Solve";
    KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
    KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
    table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(tab, solve);
    table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(enter, solve);
    table.getActionMap().put(solve, new EnterAction());

    add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    TableTest tt = new TableTest();
    tt.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

EnterAction.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EnterAction extends AbstractAction 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("actionPerformed");
        JTable tab = (JTable) e.getSource();
        if (tab.isEditing())
            tab.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();

        int row = tab.getSelectedRow();
        int col = tab.getSelectedColumn();
        System.out.println("1." + row + " " + col + " " + tab.getValueAt(row,col));

        tab.changeSelection(row,col+1,false, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no issue running your code, but you might consider add `table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(false);` and seeing if that makes a difference (or make it `true`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I tried table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(false); and true as well but did not work. Please follow the below steps to recreate the issue:  Enter a in cell(0,0) --> press enter key --> use left arrow to go to cell(0,0) --> press F2 key --> Enter b in cell(0,0) --> Press enter key --> Here action performed is not called.

Comment: Still works fine for me, what OS are you using - Works under MacOS

Comment: I am using Windows 7 enterprise edition.